# matrix for frobenius map of finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

I would be thankful if you could help me :
I have studied many things about Galois fields, but  now I am not sure about my understanding of frobenius maps. For example can anyone help me the matirx of Frobenius map on GF(8) as a vector space over GF(2)?

Comment: To represent a linear map by means of a matrix, first you need to choose a basis for $\Bbb{F}_8$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: I think we can choose twe different bases for GF(8) over GF(2). right? They are 1,x,x^2 such that due to irreducible polynomials (x^3=x+1 or x^3=x^2+1) we will have two matrices?

Comment: There are $28$ different bases for $\Bbb{F}_8$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$, and each basis allows $6$ distinct orderings. Each of these $168$ ordered bases yields a different matrix representation for the Frobenius map.

Comment: You have asked a sequence of closely related questions. Could you give some context? May be describe a thing that you do understand? It is difficult to judge what kind of an answer would help you otherwise.

Comment: @Servaes  Your comment above: "Each of these 168 ordered bases yields a different matrix representation" is well taken in that it is important to remember that the matrix representation of a linear transformation depends on our choice of a basis.  However I think it is not exactly true.  There are 56 matrices in this conjugacy class so there are 3 choices of a basis that give the same matrix.  For example in your answer below you chose the basis  (1,\alpha, \alpha^2).  The choice of either (1,\alpha^2, \alpha^2 + \alpha) or (1, \alpha^2 + \alpha, \alpha^2) also give the same matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Realising $\Bbb{F}_8$ as $\Bbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3+X+1$, we have a basis $(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)$ for $\Bbb{F}_8$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$. With respect to this basis the Frobenius map on $\Bbb{F}_8$ is represented by the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&1\end{array}\right].$$
Note that this is very much dependent on the choice of basis for $\Bbb{F}_8$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: So if I want to write the matrix form of elements of galois group as a cyclic group generated by frobenius map, what are other matrices? I mean I want to write the elemnts of Gal(GF(8)) as matrices.

Comment: Then $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{F}_8/\Bbb{F}_2)$ is (represented by) the cyclic group generated by this matrix, as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(\Bbb{F}_2^3)$, the group of invertible $3\times3$-matrices over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: please accept my appologize, I am a little bit confused , I think according to your given bases, the  second row must be 1 1 0 and third one is 1 0 1 . am I right?

Comment: I prefer to think of it in terms of columns; the vector $(1,0,0)$ corresponds to $1\in\Bbb{F}_8$ and is mapped to itself. The vector $(0,1,0)$ corresponds to $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_8$ which is mapped to $\alpha^2$, which corresponds to the vector $(0,0,1)$. The vector $(0,0,1)$ corresponds to $\alpha^2$ in $\Bbb{F}_8$, which is mapped to $\alpha+\alpha^2$ corresponding to the vector $(1,1,0)$.